# Amazon AWS SSL Problems

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3

I'm currently hosting an S3 bucket with a static website, I'm using an SSL certificate via certificate manager that covers *.domain.com. Visiting the site www.domain.com results in a secure website, however simply going to domain.com does not even though the A record for domain.com points to www.domain.com through Route 53. The specific error message states that the site can't provide a secure connection, my question is, is the DNS not setup correctly to point domain.com to www.domain.com or is it because the SSL certificate is only for *.domain.com and not domain.com.

Secure: https://www.adambarlowlaw.com/
Insecure: https://adambarlowlaw.com/

Answer (score 1):

Pointing domain.com to www.domain.com just has the effect of two separate records that both end up pointing to the same IP address. Lots of people mistake this sort of DNS pointer as a browser redirect, but that is not the case.

You are focusing on the DNS setup, but it is the SSL certificate that is incorrect. Since the server has both domain.com and www.domain.com pointing at it, the server needs to be able to serve both of those domains. You have configured the SSL certificate to work for *.domain.com but not domain.com.

When you request an SSL certificate you need to request two domains `domain.com` and `*.domain.com`